# Filter out an object in array of objects

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my silly question.I have a list of users like this:

```
const users = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"],age:20},
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["AWS", "Python"],age:15 },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"],age:21},
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"],age:22},
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"],age:34 },
    { name: "Sara", skills: ["PHP", "AWS"],age:23 },
    { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:25 },
     { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:10 },
];
```

I want to filter out Matt with the age of 25

```
const JavaScriptApplicants = users.filter(o => o.name !== 'Matt' && o.age !== 25);
console.log(JavaScriptApplicants)
```

But it filters out another one with age 10. I just want the 25 gone.

Comment: change `&&` to `||`

Comment: OMG, that's correct. But what is the logic here? I think we need 2 conditions is true right?

Comment: When you want to keep an item your callback should return `true`. If `o.name` is Matt then `o.name !== Matt` will be `false`, making the entire expression evaluate to `false`, on the other hand, `||` will ensure that the name is both Matt and the age is 25 before evaluating to `false`

Comment: Thank you, guys. Hope the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need OR instead of AND.

The reason is simple. If you take

```
 !(o.name === 'Matt' && o.age === 25)
```

read: if name equals matt and age equals 25 don't take it.

Then take [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> ```
> !(a && b) = !a || !b
> !(a || b) = !a && !b
> ```

and convert the expression into one without NOT, you get

```
 !(o.name === 'Matt') || !(o.age === 25)
 o.name !== 'Matt' || o.age !== 25
```

```js
const users = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"],age:20},
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["AWS", "Python"],age:15 },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"],age:21},
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"],age:22},
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"],age:34 },
    { name: "Sara", skills: ["PHP", "AWS"],age:23 },
    { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:25 },
     { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:10 },
     { name: "Foo", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:25 },
];


const JavaScriptApplicants = users.filter(o => o.name !== 'Matt' || o.age !== 25);
console.log(JavaScriptApplicants)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OMG, that's correct. But what is the logic here? I think we need 2 conditions is true right?

Comment: @kapilpandey, please see the edit. it works. please jhave a look to the expressions as well.

Comment: @kapilpandey why should this not work? if a other users has a age of 25 it wouldnt even reach the right side of the `||` operator if the name isnt Matt

Answer (score 2):

```js
const users = [
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["Docker", "JavaScript", "Ruby"],age:20},
    { name: "Jimmy", skills: ["AWS", "Python"],age:15 },
    { name: "Frankie", skills: ["Azure", "JavaScript"],age:21},
    { name: "Liam", skills: ["Java", "JavaScript"],age:22},
    { name: "Fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"],age:34 },
    { name: "Sara", skills: ["PHP", "AWS"],age:23 },
    { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:25 },
     { name: "Matt", skills: [".Net", "PHP", "Docker"],age:10 },
];


const JavaScriptApplicants = users.filter(o => !(o.name === "Matt" && o.age === 25));
console.log(JavaScriptApplicants)
```